# Mapbox GL JS Set Paint property on specific Feature in Layer

Tags: mapbox, mouseover, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-studio

I am using Mapbox Studio as basis for mapping and styling and then using HTML for additional map features.

One of the features is to change Icon opacity when hovering or mouse enter. I've checked other examples and all other refer to feature when you create it directly in HTML. I managed to change opacity but only for whole layer.

Can I use somehow e.features[0] command line to apply changes only to one feature rather than to whole layer?

I used this code which changer opacity for whole Layer 'Icon' (Layer contains 5 icons with text):

```
    // Change the cursor to a default and change opacity when the it enters a feature in the 'Icons' layer.
map.on('mouseenter', 'Icons', function() {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'default';
    var feature = e.features[0];
    map.setPaintProperty('Icons', 'icon-opacity', 0.5);
});

// Change it back to a pointer and reset opacity when it leaves.
map.on('mouseleave', 'Icons', function() {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '',
    map.setPaintProperty('Icons', 'icon-opacity', 1);
});
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: You should read up on Expressions in the style spec. You can use these to change display properties based on feature attributes. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/

Answer (score 10):

There are a few ways which you could achieve this. One approach is to add each feature as separate layer, so that when you want to change the opacity of an icon added in a layer `'specific-icon-layer'`, you can pass `'specific-icon-layer'` to the `Map#on` method. This is likely the most straightforward option if you have a relatively minimal number of markers.

Another approach is to add unique IDs to each icon feature, so that you can use a `filter` expression in conjunction with [`Map#setPaintProperty`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setpaintproperty) and [`Map#queryRenderedFeatures`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#queryrenderedfeatures) (or [`Map#querySourceFeatures`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#querysourcefeatures)). For example, suppose you add an `'id'` property to each GeoJSON feature representing an icon in the source for the `'Icons'` layer. Then, you could set up an event listener similar to [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/), retrieve the `'id'` of the returned feature, and use the `'id'` (suppose here it is `'example-id'`) to update the paint property for the `'Icons'` layer:

```
map.setPaintProperty(
  'Icons', 
  'icon-opacity', 
  ['match', ['get', 'id'], 'example-id', 0.5 , 1]
);
```

Here, we use [`match`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#match) and [`get`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#get) expressions to say "if the `'id'` of a feature is `'example-id'`, paint its icon with opacity `0.5`, otherwise use opacity `1`."

Comment: Can a `setPaintProperty` be used on individual road line segments that share the same layer?

Comment: The example code will have poor performance for hover-interaction when the layer has a lot of features (consider that it actually touches styles of each feature on the layer, not just the filtered one.)  It is better to query for the feature and use [setFeatureState](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#setfeaturestate). feature-state styles can be preset for the layer style using a [feature-state expression](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#feature-state)

Answer (score 0):

Check the example at https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/

This approach makes use of [setFeatureState](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#setfeaturestate) and [feature-state expressions](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#feature-state)

The problem with using `map.setPaintProperty(layer, property, filter, matchValue, styleValue, fallbackStyleValue)` every time is that it restyles every feature on the layer instead of only the feature being interacted with.  This can cause poor performance when the layer has a high number of features.